# how to make infinite floor with A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I need to make a huge floor (looks like infinite) in my virtual world with A-frame. How can I do it? I tried to put many boxes in the floor but doesn't looks too good...

```
      <a-box color="#FFF" width="10" height="0.5" depth="10"
             position="0 -10 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="2 0.5 3"
             src="#texture_0"></a-box>
      <a-box color="#FFF" width="10" height="0.5" depth="10"
             position="20 -10 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="2 0.5 3"
             src="#texture_0"></a-box>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done before is made one huge box as the floor, say 200x200, then set a sky with a position of -200 so it sits "lower" on the scene and gives the illusion of the ground expanding into infinity. I'm using an ocean in this example, but it would work with a box too.

It looks like this: [image: Infinite ocean A-Frame]

Code:

```
<a-ocean width="200" depth="200" density="40" opacity="1" position="0 -0.4 0"></a-ocean>
<a-sky src="#sky" position="0 -200 0"></a-sky>
```

Comment: what texture did you used for the ocean because this is awesome

Comment: There's an `<a-ocean>` component: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/primitives/a-ocean.js

Comment: How do I get this blue ring in the middle of the scene?